# Can't select the "map_gc" dom in arcgis js api by d3.js (arcgis js api 3.31)

Tags: d3.js, arcgis-js-api

I create a demo to test the svg layer reserved by arcgis js api.But I can't use D3 to select it.

```
    require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "dojo/_base/array",
        "dojo/dom",
        "dojo/number",
        "dojo/on",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dojo/ready"
    ], function (Map, FeatureLayer, array, dom, number, on, parser, ready) {
        parser.parse();

        var map = new Map("map", {
                basemap: "gray",
                center: [139.742661, 35.371135],
                zoom: 5
            });

        ready(function () {
            var g =d3.select("#map_gc").append("h1");
            console.log(g)
        });

    });
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA4nc.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Without the HTML code, it seems pretty complicated to help you. Maybe could you provide a template on CodePen or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Fine,it's a simple bug.Js is executed before the dom is loaded.Just use the window.onload() method.Like this:

```
            window.onload = function () {
            var g = d3.select("#map_gc").append("h1");
            console.log(g)
            }
```

But I cant understand why the ready() method doesn't work.